# ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to call a lambda function which will push some messages into the s3 bucket.But every time i am calling the lambda function i am getting the below  error

```
 ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied
```

Below is my lambda code

```
import json
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
s3 = boto3.client("s3")
#data = json.loads(event["Records"][0]["body"])
data = event["Records"][0]["body"]

s3.put_object(Bucket="sqsmybucket",Key="data.json", Body=json.dumps(data))
#print(event) 
return {
    'statusCode': 200,
    'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')     
}
```

I am using a user account which also has the role to access the S3 [image]

I have checked the s3 bucket permission and all public access are open for it

[image]

But i am repeatedly getting below  error message in cloudwatch log

```
2020-06-05T23:48:20.920+05:30

[ERROR] ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 9, in lambda_handler
  s3.put_object(Bucket="sqsmybucket",Key="data.json", Body=json.dumps(data))
 File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 316, in _api_call
 return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
 File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 626, in _make_api_call
  raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
```

[image]
[image]

Please help i am really clueless about the situation.Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Lambda role needs to have permissions for S3. Also please remove your account id

Comment: When you run code inside lambda function, your user account permission doesn't apply there. You need to create an IAM role and attach that to the lambda function.

Comment: @jellycsc already role is attached, see my edited post

Comment: @Mandrek You need to give that role `s3:PutObject` permission.

Comment: @jellycsc how i can do that ?

Comment: @Mandrek Please join the chat room and I will show you how to do it. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215391/room-for-jellycsc-and-mandrek

Comment: @jellycsc Thanks for the help , it worked

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Please make sure the role attached to the lambda function has the `s3:PutObject` permission.

For example, the least privilege/permission needed is

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:PutObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Notice the `/*` at the end of the resource string. The reason why `/*` is needed is because according to the [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazons3.html), the PutObject action has an **object** resource type. [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazons3.html#amazons3-object) is the definition of the object resource type. Basically, `*` is matching all possible S3 object keys, and the stuff to the left of `/` is limiting its scope down to a single S3 bucket.

Comment: the "/*" is the key

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, apparently, you don't have to just use the ARN of the bucket, but also include the "/*" at the end of it.
It's important to always use the Least Privileged pattern when granting permissions.

Answer (score 1):

In case I'm not the only one in this:

```
  MyLambda:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Policies:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - s3:PutObject
            Resource: !GetAtt MyBucket.Arn
```

^ won't work. The last sentence needs to be changed to:

```
            Resource: !Sub "${MyBucket.Arn}/*"
```